# Sum only positive values and display negative values as 0 on a table visual in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to build a table visual here in my Power BI report. From 2 different columns, I make a calculation from them, subtracting one from another. My problem is: I need to subtract the values and show 0 value when I have a negative result from the calculation. And I want to show the total sum in the final string, as a sum of only the positive values.

Please look through this example bellow:

[image: Example 1]

I tried to use:

Result Column =
IF( SUM(Column 1) > SUM( Column 2); 0; SUM(Column 2) - SUM(Column 1) )

But my table visual show me the total result as zero:

[image: Result example]

Is there any option to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Code:

```
Column = MAX( 'Table'[Column2] - 'Table'[Column1] ,0)
```

Comment: The total sum value keeps showing 0 :(

Comment: Can you share a .pbix?

Comment: I'll update my answer now with screenshots.

Comment: I'm sorry, but not really. I need this function to work as a measure, because I'm using it on a table visual and not in a direct table.

Comment: It should work if you replace the code as follows: Measure = MAX( measure1 - measure2,0)

Answer (score 0):

The measure is recalculated for the grand total; it's not just the sum of the values for each row.  So you need to bake that behavior into the measure definition like this:

`Measure = sumx('Table',max('Table'[Column2]-'Table'[Column1],0))`

[image]

Comment: Looks interesting your measure, but can I use this if my Column2 comes from a different table than the Column1 ?

Comment: My Column2 is a measure from one table and my Column1 is a measure from another one.